# Actionscript 3.0 Power calculator (exponant)

Tags: actionscript

I have a project I need to do for my online class and I can not figure out how to do this. So it is suppose to be a program where you put a base and an exponent.

Let's say your base was 4 and exponent was 3 it should give an answer that looks like this. 4 exponent `0 = 1 4` exponent `1 = 4 4` exponent `2 = 16 4` exponent `3 = 64`.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not do your homework for you.  Please show what you have tried so far and post a specific problem you are having with your code.

[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you check the AS3 manual about Math API? Which part of the [**Pow(er)**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#pow()) command is not working? If you want to list all the in-between exponents (from `0` to `3`) you'll have to use a `For-loop` to repeat the instructions.